# input blur doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.newBill').find('input').focus(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('roomNumber')){
            return false;
        }else{
            $('.roomNumber').change(function(){
                if($('.roomNumber').val() != null && $('.roomNumber').val() != ""){
                    roomNumberFocusOut(".roomNumber");
                }else{
                    getSystemMessage('Please enter a room number to proceed.');
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

I use the above code to fire a method only if the user changes the focus out from the `.roomNumber` to another input. then I check whether the input on the `.roomNumber` element is changed so that if not changed not to fire the function. but this doesn't get fired when the focus is changed using the mouse. instead if i use the tab to go to the next element it gets fired. what can I do to make the function fire in mouse click on another input.

Comment: Why nested change handler inside focus one?

Comment: 'input:not:(.roomNumber)'

Comment: this is actually designed for a touch device and there is a onscreen number pad displayed. ( html designed ) so I cannot fire on change on the input cus there is another function going on to add the value to the input on the number button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use blur event of input http://api.jquery.com/blur/